# "Netconsole Module Not Loaded" When Trying To Check All Services

Tags: centos7, service

I have a fairly new server build and I'm trying to list all the services.  Checking the status of any one works fine, but running `service --status-all` gives the error:

> netconsole module not loaded
>   Configured devices:
>   lo eno16777736
>   Currently active devices
>   lo eno16777736

---

[I tried following this advice that says if you don't explicitly need netconsole, you should disable it](https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_6/2013-06-03/finding/V-38672).  Which provides these instructions:

- Output should indicate the "netconsole" service has either not been installed, or has been disabled at all runlevels, as shown in the example below: `chkconfig "netconsole" --list`

  > netconsole 0:off 1:off 2:off 3:off 4:off 5:off 6:off

  - My output is

    > netconsole 0:off 1:off 2:on 3:on 4:on 5:on 6:off
- Run the following command to verify "netconsole" is disabled through current runtime configuration: `service netconsole status`. If the service is disabled the command will return the following output:

  > netconsole is stopped

  - However, my output is:

    > netconsole module not loaded
- The "netconsole" service can be disabled with the following command: `chkconfig netconsole off`

  - This changes all the values in step 1 to "off", but this doesn't make a difference.

---

I also tried `service netconsole stop`

---

[I tried manually loading/unloading the module.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules)

```
modprobe netconsole
modprobe -r netconsole
```

---

I found a workaround, but I would still like to know how I can fix this.

Comment: I haven't fixed the problem, but I can accomplish what I wanted with `systemctl list-unit-files -t service`

Answer (score 4):

This is due to the switch from init.d to systemd for system services. Check out /etc/init.d/README, which contains a little information about how to live in the new world but doesn't explicitly mention that the `service` command is now pretty much deprecated.

Comment: So what's the new way of doing "service --status-all"? EDIT: looks like "systemctl" will do this?

Comment: You can use `systemctl list-units --type service` [More information here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/check-running-services-in-rhel-redhat-fedora-centoslinux/)